# Is there a way to make vim run the “make” command in another terminal window?

Tags: c++, c, vim, cmake, terminal

I mainly use vim as an editor for C/C++ programming. Unfortunately, I'm not quite satisfied with the way my build process works. I know that it's possible to type in (or map to a key) `:make` to run the make process. I dislike the way this command works, though, as it runs the build process in the same terminal window without proper highlighting. I therefore usually run the make command in another window on my second monitor so that I have both proper highlighting and can look at the build errors the compiler shows me in one window while scrolling through the source code in my main vim window. This is also quite tedious because it requires me to change focus to another window, then type in the make command.

Now, my question is as follows: Is it possible to make vim run the make command in this other window without having to change focus? This way, I could just map the "build in other window" command to some key in vim and could achieve all of this with a single key press.

My system is Manjaro Linux with i3 as DWM.

(I was unsure wether to post this on the unix forum or here, please forgive me if this is the wrong forum.)

Comment: Does this help: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window ?

Comment: You use `cmake` tag but your question notes `make` utility. So, which utility you actually asked about, CMake or Make? They are different things.

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you can have a shell script running in your second window that, in a loop, sits around waiting for something (trying to read a named pipe (c.f. `mkfifo`)?) before running your colorized `make` or whatever, and then you just create a mapping in `vim` to trigger it (e.g. write to the pipe).

Comment: It is not apparent from your question so I will ask: do you know about `:help quickfix`?

Comment: I've added support for forcefully [coloured error messages](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/doc/make_run.md#colours) in my _BTW_ plugin -- only in `project` branch for now. The compilation is done within Vim (with an asynchronous flavour of `:make`), focus doesn't go to the quickfix (vim) window, and escape codes produced by gcc are interpreted. Three plugins will need to be installed.

Comment: There are plugins to run the make command asynchronously, then you can have access to quickfix without locking your editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using xdotool and i3 config-file mappings. These mappings require that the last command executed in the terminal of the window rightwards was `make`.

```
set $prevR    xdotool key --clearmodifiers --delay 2 super+l ctrl+p Return super+h
set $prevRclr xdotool key --clearmodifiers --delay 2 super+l ctrl+l ctrl+p Return super+h
```

And then map those commands to your preferred keys, for example:

```
bindsym --release Mod4+Shift+e exec --no-startup-id $prevR 
bindsym --release Mod4+e       exec --no-startup-id $prevRclr
```

The first mapping runs the previous command on the window right to the current one.
The second one does the same while first clearing the terminal. You need to substitute the `super+[lh]` with your own mappings that change the focus to your alternate monitor.
You may also have to increase the `--delay` to accommodate for the lag of changing windows.

If you also want to populate the quickfix list, you have to separately run `:make` in vim. By doing this you can both see the errors properly colored and formatted on your alternate monitor and be able to jump to the next error in vim with `:cnext`, `:cprevious` (see `:help quickfix.txt` for more info).

If you want to apply your make command to an arbitrary window, have a look at the
'WINDOW_STACK' section of the man page `xdotool(1)`.